# Laravel 5 GET api call is working but POST api calls are not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

How to disable CSRF verification on API routes in laravel?

In the `API routes` I am calling a function through POST and GET method. GET methord returning data's but POST method throwing method not found exception.

Here is my sample code in `routes/api.php`

```
Route::post('hellopostapi', function() {
    return json_encode( 'we are getting POST response');
});

Route::get('helloget', function() {
    return json_encode( 'we are getting GET response);
});
```

For GET call i am getting the response as expected.
And for POST i am getting this exception

> "message": "",
>       "exception":"Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException",
>
> ```
> "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php",
>
> "line": 255,
>
> "trace": [
>     {
>         "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php",
>
>         "line": 242,
>
>         "function": "methodNotAllowed",
>
>         "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection",
>
>         "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>         "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php",
>         "line": 176,
>         "function": "getRouteForMethods",
>         "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection",
>         "type": "->"
>     },
> ```

I also added api routes in verifycsrf.php , as per documentation it should work, unfortunatly its not working for me. 
here is my `verifiycsrf.php`

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'api/*',
    ];
}
```

API Testing screenshot
**POST request which causing issue**
[image]

**Get request which is working fine**
[image]
That's still not working. Can anyone please help me .Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you are using the `POST` method. the function on line 242 is the `GET` method

Comment: **MethodNotAllowedHttpException** means that your request is not correct, you probably make a POST when the route expects GET or vice versa. The *api* routes do not go through the CSRF middleware by default.

Comment: yes,i am making post request. I am testing with postman

Comment: Try adding `_method` as `POST` to your request. see docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#form-method-spoofing

Comment: This is api call cant add _method

Comment: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/requests look for Request Body

Comment: @Mike Hi, mike i am not passing any parameter it just simple post call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking deeper into this, i found out that this was never a laravel issue, rather it was causing due to HTTP to HTTPS redirection.
After changing http to https the problem seems to resloved. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the form method you are posting from, it's highly likely that the method is GET method yet in your routes file you have configured it to expect a POST method

Comment: This is an API call no form submission and i m testing the api with POSTMAN

Comment: Please share a code snippet of how you are calling the route

Comment: Hi, i updated the question with a screenshot of my apicalling

Comment: Updated the question with get request screenshot